# Cannot find home directory on Linux Server

Tags: ssh, permissions, find, home-directory

I have recently been granted access to a Linux server where I transferred some data. Now, for some reason, when I use WinSCP or any other program to connect to the server, instead of logging in directly into my home directory (where I have my files and where I have write and read privileges) I am in /root. Needless to say, I cannot do anything in /root and I cannot find my home directory. Any advice??

Comment: `/home/yourusername`?

Comment: the /home directory is empty

Comment: Talk with the administrator of this server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo $HOME` should show what the system thinks is your home directory. That requires access to a terminal of course.

Comment: I will try this..

Comment: This is probably the best way since the SCP protocol doesn't load environment variables. You'll need to use putty or some other SSH client to login for this.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't return anything. Hmm, now that I look at it more carefully, as soon as I login into the server it writes the following message: "Could not chdir to home directory /home/myusername: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/xauth:  error in locking authority file /home/myusername/.Xauthority" . What does it mean? How can I still be allowed to login if my account doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: Your account exists, but the home directory is unavailable. It may be lost, not mounted, misconfigured, etc. You should get in touch with the server administrator.

Comment: I understand: thanks a lot for everybody's help. I will do just that.

Answer (score 0):

If echo $HOME gives you blanc, just simply type
cd /

Then change the directory to your home.
it should reveal the home directory. It works for me, hope this helps.